# WebAPI Type of method that returns either Class or Error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, error-handling

I'd want to ask about way to return errors when it comes to WebAPI

I'm not sure whether I should use this approach, because this is not giving really good details except 500 internal server error code without UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

```
public async Task<Token> login(User creds)
{
    var user = await Task.FromResult(_context.GetUser.....);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid credentials");
    }

    return BuildToken(user); // Task<Token>
}

public class Token
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public long Expires { get; set; }
}
```

So, should I create dynamic json and cast Error model / my JWT model to that dynamic json or something like that?

Basically I'd want to return either:

```
{
    "Token": "aaaaa.aaaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "Expires": "111111111"
}
    or
{
    "message": "Invalid credentials"
}
```

Comment: Return a `IActionResult` instead. Also, why are you doing `Task.FromResult` here? Don't do that, just make the method non-async.

Comment: @DavidG Please write it as an answer, i'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details:

Use method type:
`IActionResult`

and return errors as e.g

```
return new BadRequestObjectResult
(
    new { message = "error message"}
);
```